# How do I send pull-request that implements Travis to another repository which I do not own?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I sometimes see other repositories that does not have Travis implemented. I want to fork these repos, create an appropriate `.travis.yml`.

The problem is that I do not own these repos and I don't really have any idea how Travis will work due to this situation. Some questions I have:

- Will the owner(s) of that repository need to create a Travis account? Should I inform them about creating a Travis account somehow before they merge?
- Or will Travis trigger builds without the owner creating a Travis account at all? If so, will it trigger these builds under my account or an account that has the same (probably) Github username?
- Is setting up Travis on another repository that you do not own a good idea anyway? I think there may be limitations such as a hidden environment variable will not be shared to repository's owner, maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A collaborator on the repo will need to sign to Travis with their GitHub account to enable it. And yes, they'll need to set any appropriate configuration the build needs. Maybe best not to do it unilaterally; not least because there are other options than Travis the maintainers might prefer. Why not *ask what they want first?*

Comment: Continuous integration alternatives can be discussed under an open issue. It is Travis because, I don't know. It is used widely in open source projects, maybe? More importantly, I chose Travis to be more specific. What I wonder is what kind of experience one's had, of course if he/she has had about applying Travis to another repo. I think the question might provide a general scenario/answer if anyone wants to implement *any* kind of continuous integration platform to another repository.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I send pull-request that implements Travis to another repository which I do not own?

- regarding the files to add (like a `.travis`), this is done through a regular PR (pull-request), which means you have forked the repo first, and tested the process there.
- regarding the configuration part (Travis account), this is done through the associated comment to the PR, with detailed instructions for the maintainer of the original project you would have forked to complete the procedure.